# How to write to multiple outputs on a TLV5620CN over SPI?

Tags: spi

How can I write to multiple output DACs at the same time? This is the function I am using.

```
int DACCodes[4];
void writeVoltageSPI(int channel, float v, float maxV)
{
    int code = (int)(256 * v / maxV);
    unsigned char buffer[2];
    if (v <= maxV)
    {
        buffer[0] = (channel - 1) & 0x07;
        buffer[1] = code & 0xFF;
        SpiWriteAndRead(0, buffer, NULL, 2, 0);
        setValue(LDAC_PIN, 0);
        setValue(LDAC_PIN, 1);
    }
}
```

Every time I do a write, it sets each other DAC to 0 V.

Thanks for the help

https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/spi/using-the-spi-interface

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv5620.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1686664223841&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftlv5620